# How is the following question Scientific Speculation or not related to Hinduism?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[How does a Swan separate milk and water, as claimed by Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28287/how-does-a-swan-separate-milk-and-water-as-claimed-by-hindu-scriptures)

The question only asks how it happens.

The question does not ask how is it "scientifically" possible or so.

Also, it is by no means off topic to Hinduism. Hinduism has this belief about Swans, so asking how Hinduism tells the swan is able to do, is not off topic to Hinduism.

Comment: Isn't it asking a skeptical reason behind the belief?

Answer (score 5):

I do voted to close this question as off-topic and there is certain reason behind this act. The reason I provided in the comment (which I deleted accidentally) is:

> "It's not in the scope of Hinduism scriptures to explain each and
>   every phenomenon in detail. Thousands of such questions can be asked
>   as there are thousands of such examples are present in scriptures. "

And Yes  I think it's not in scope of hinduism scriptures to explain **"How Stuff Works"**  in brief or in detail.

Hinduism scriptures are using examples of behavior of animals , plants and phenomenons of nature etc.  by observation  to explain spiritual terms in simple manner for better understanding and easy grasping. But its not the work and the scope  of the sacred  scriptures to explain the technicalities behind those behaviors , traits or phenomenons. The scriptures simply deals with spiritual enquiry and spiritual progress , the ultimate goal of which is to lead us to Moksha. And not to indulge in curious enquiry of functioning of it. But rather a high enquiry of who is behind the  functioning of all of the things. i.e. **Brahman**.

We can see this all around often . There are separate branches of knowledge for each topic even the topic is related to main branch Like there is separate branch of physics to explain quantum nature of particles i.e. quantum physics , optics , thermal science  etc .Lets take example of Photography . The Manual of photography will only tell you about the terms useful in clicking photos and it will just provide us an example that" Light only travels in straight line" and the camera by employing this technique will focus the rays on receiver and will take a photo"

But the actual formulas,  maths ,  optics , laws etc. is domain of branch of Physics. We will find the detail of how actually lenses work and in Electronics how the CCD or CMOS converts the light into image and the technical definitions related to that. But it's not the scope of subject of Photography to technically explain equations , laws and workings of components etc.

In the same way Hinduism Scriptures are the texts related with the spirituality and the terms associated with it. Not related with explaining the phenomena and examples provided in those just for understanding of terms.

So that is the reason  why I do voted to close the question.

Comment: Your answer not convincing at all. Purpose of Hinduism is precisely to explain all phenomenon on earth and beyond. Like there is astrology we have Jyotishi, like there is metalogic we have Nyaya Shastra, like there is medical science we have Ayurveda. Like there are elements in periodic table we have panch mahabhoo which make up physical world. So please don't close questions like these.